# You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE)

Tags: ios, angular, capacitor

getting this error with my capacitor angular IOS project build. No idea how to make it go away. The app runs fine on the simulator, but won't archive.

My current version of Xcode has no options for turning bitcode on or off as its long since been deprecated.

By the way, I recently added Admob, so not sure if that is part of the problem.

`'/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-agxukbuoctkyprdbhocbssyatgbg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement(APMAdExposureReporter.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-agxukbuoctkyprdbhocbssyatgbg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement' for architecture arm64`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this after removing all references in the app to adMob and Adsense. must have been something conflicting with it.